# Windows Azure xml comments file not found

Tags: xml, azure, asp.net-core, swagger, azure-app-service-plans

I've recently published my web application to a windows API app service plan on Azure, and since have been having multiple issues with the XML docs I am using for swagger.

I'm getting an error 500:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\Zwekness.Api.xml'
```

At first the file wasn't being added when publishing, having done that manually I can now 100% confirm the file is on the server
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjMJE.png), yet I am getting the exact same error.
I'm out of ideas what could be causing this behaviour ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure that XML documentation file in Project Properties | Build | Output is set for debug and release configuration.
2. Be sure that you copied the xml file in the correct path. If you just specify a file name in step one then you need to have the xml file in your wwwroot folder.